# Is there such a thing as an IP femtocell, and what does it do?

Tags: mobile-phone, ip, cellular

My dad mentioned a co-worker suggested using a device, that might use CDMA to route calls through IP to save costs on a certain overseas project we're on- since our home base is quite far from there. I've never heard of such a device, so if it does exist, I'm wondering, if it's specific to particular ISPs, or if you can just pick one off the shelf, plug it into an  arbitrary Internet connection, and make calls using it and a cellphone of some sort?

As you can tell, details are sketchy, so... if such a device doesn't exist, saying so might be a right answer ;)

Comment: just for the record... it was something totally different they were talking about. i've selected the closest answer to what i thought was being talked about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different cell carriers offer femtocells, as well as Magicjack who is about to release one.  You may want to consider using phones that simply integrate with normal wifi through UMA.  I get crap service where I am, but my phone just patches into my access point at home and doesn't have trouble.

Comment: Thats a possibility - if femtocells are CDMA we'd have to get a seperate set of phones anyway.

Comment: +1 to DHayes. @JoruneymanGeek Magicjack does exactly what you asked: http://www.magicjack.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can just plug it in, it does not require a specific ISP (that would be a nightmare). You may have problems trying to use the femtocell overseas to connect to a wireless provider in the US.

You should consider VOIP\Skype\google voice, etc.

Comment: we're not US based - our home base is in singapore, and we might have a remote office in another country, and we'd like to save on roaming charges. We'll almost certainly be using skype or some other VOIP service in addition to the device. I'd just like some extra info before i brought up the idea

One system they have here (starhub homezone) is tied into both a specific ISP and phone company, which is why i wondered

Answer (score 0):

From the Wikipedia article on [Femtocell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Femtocell):

> In telecommunications, a
>   **femtocell**—originally known as an
>   Access Point Base Station—is a small
>   cellular base station, typically
>   designed for use in a home or small
>   business. It connects to the service
>   provider’s network via broadband (such
>   as DSL or cable); current designs
>   typically support 2 to 4 active mobile
>   phones in a residential setting, and 8
>   to 16 active mobile phones in
>   enterprise settings. A femtocell
>   allows service providers to extend
>   service coverage indoors, especially
>   where access would otherwise be
>   limited or unavailable. The femtocell
>   incorporates the functionality of a
>   typical base station but extends it to
>   allow a simpler, self contained
>   deployment; an example is a UMTS
>   femtocell containing a Node B, RNC and
>   in some cases GPRS Support Node (SGSN)
>   with Ethernet for backhaul. Although
>   much attention is focused on **WCDMA**,
>   the concept is applicable to all
>   standards, including GSM, **CDMA2000**,
>   **TD-SCDMA**, WiMAX and LTE solutions.

There is a ton more information in that article.  I won't repeat it all here, but there are several pieces of discussion in there about "lub over IP" and VoIP with terminal adapters, etc.

Comment: Read through it, but it isn't very specidic about some of the quetions i had, especially to do with actual models.